# runtime error when changing chart object property

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change a chart object properties. Each time I try to run the code, every things are OK except the following which shows runtime error 2147467259(80004005) Method 'insideLeft' of object plotarea failed.

```
        With ShapeObj.Chart.PlotArea
            .InsideLeft = 20
            .InsideTop = 0
            .InsideWidth = 290
            .InsideHeight = 290
        End With
```

But when I click debug and go to vba editor and hit F5 to continue running it works!
How can I sole this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the chart object selected before reaching `With` block?

Comment: No. I put select before it and problem resolved. Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to select the chart for it work (*Though selecting the chart works*). The only reason I feel (*It is just my opinion and I can be wrong*) this happens because the chartobject is not *ready*. Here is an example to demonstrate that.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ShapeObj As ChartObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ShapeObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 200, 100)

    ShapeObj.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=Range("A1:B4"), _
    Gallery:=xlColumn, Format:=6, PlotBy:=xlColumns, _
    CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=1
    
    With ShapeObj.Chart.PlotArea
            .InsideLeft = 20
            .InsideTop = 0
            .InsideWidth = 290
            .InsideHeight = 290
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code should give you an error. Selecting the chartobject, `ShapeObj.Select` will take care of the error as mentioned in the comment above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ShapeObj As ChartObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ShapeObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 200, 100)

    ShapeObj.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=Range("A1:B4"), _
    Gallery:=xlColumn, Format:=6, PlotBy:=xlColumns, _
    CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=1
    
    ShapeObj.Select
    
    With ShapeObj.Chart.PlotArea
            .InsideLeft = 20
            .InsideTop = 0
            .InsideWidth = 290
            .InsideHeight = 290
    End With
End Sub
```

Below is another way to achieve what you want without having to select the chart.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ShapeObj As ChartObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ShapeObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 200, 100)

    ShapeObj.Chart.ChartWizard Source:=Range("A1:B4"), _
    Gallery:=xlColumn, Format:=6, PlotBy:=xlColumns, _
    CategoryLabels:=1, SeriesLabels:=0, HasLegend:=1
    
    '~~> Wait for 1 second. Just DoEvents will not solve the issue
    Wait 1
    
    With ShapeObj.Chart.PlotArea
            .InsideLeft = 20
            .InsideTop = 0
            .InsideWidth = 290
            .InsideHeight = 290
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you are still facing this porblem after introducing `Wait 1`, then post the full code in your so that we can have a look.

Comment: `yes it works too – Hamed 9 mins ago` Glad it worked for you